# Laravel File Downloads do not require Auth once you download them and logout

Tags: laravel, file, authentication, download

My team and I ran into a strange Laravel bug that we cannot find a good solution for after searching for a couple hours and trying various fixes. We have tested this in laravel 5.7, 5.8, and even updated to laravel 6 to see if it would help and we have the same result.

The issue:

We implemented a download route so we can easily download files from our storage folder. We wrapped this route behind some Middleware including the user access level and the Auth Middleware. Everything seems to work great, users can click the links in the application and easily download the files and you can even directly put the links in the URL to download the files. The issue came up when we were testing where you do not need to be logged in to download files. We have tracked the issue down to a certain path outlined below.

1. Login to application. (Prior to login you cannot download files by putting them in browser, get 403 like we expected)
2. Download any files you wish, we will call the specific file downloaded, "File#1".
3. Logout of application.
4. At this point there should be no auth. You cannot access any pages or any files that you did not just download in your previous session. However... if you try to put the path of one of the files you just downloaded such as "File#1".. The file downloads to the client even though there should be auth on it. This seems like the auth is somehow saving to the download itself and skipping all auth. Any other file that was not downloaded can not be downloaded until you log in to the application like expected.

Code below:

Logout Method:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Route:

```
        Route::get('/download/{file}', array(
            'as' => 'download',
            'uses' => 'GeneratePDFController@download'
        ))->where('file', '.*')->middleware('auth');
```

Middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Download Controller:

```
    public function download($file)
    {   
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/public/' . $file));
    }
```

If we clear the cache on our browsers it fixes the issues until you login and download a new file. Also after logout you are completely blocked from every other route(even the ones that only require auth) until you log back in. The previously download files seem to be the only things breaking this rule. Our file names are complex enough where this is not a major security risk since they are only available for the current user session, but I do not feel comfortable leaving this behavior in place.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance everyone, I'll try to keep up a bit later in case anyone responds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set "don't cache me!" headers along with the download:

```
return response()
    ->withHeaders([
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        'Expires' => '0'
    ])
    ->download(storage_path('app/public/' . $file));
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Thank you for such a quick and helpful answer! Hopefully this helps others in the future, this caused us many hours of pain! 

Thanks again for the easy to implement fix!